# How do I get characters from EditText?

Tags: android, string, character, android-edittext, forceclose

I want to get the String from an EditText and then read individual characters from it. I've tried the following code:

```
String PT = pt.getText().toString(); 
int len = PT.length(); 
char chars[] = PT.toCharArray(); 
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{ Toast.makeText(encrypt.this,chars[i], 0).show(); }
```

However I get a Force Close error on this. Where am I going wrong?

I'm quite new to all this!

Here's the LogCat:

```
11-28 12:41:01.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 12:41:01.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 12:41:01.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 12:41:01.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 12:41:01.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 12:41:01.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 12:46:43.688: W/KeyCharacterMap(1674): No keyboard for id 0
11-28 12:46:43.688: W/KeyCharacterMap(1674): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-28 12:46:54.442: W/ResourceType(1674): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000061
11-28 12:46:54.448: D/AndroidRuntime(1674): Shutting down VM
11-28 12:46:54.448: W/dalvikvm(1674): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x61
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.project.DENCrypt.encrypt$1.onClick(encrypt.java:33)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 12:46:54.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I just posted the LogCat

Comment: probably the edit text (layout resource)is not available when reading the data from it. Just check whether you are able to get no null value when you do EditText edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditView);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your toast message to

```
Toast.makeText(encrypt.this,Character.toString(chars[i]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here the problem is with Toast message. Toast can not Display charaters. so convert charater to string and display

Comment: Thanks a mil! The code was actually working well, just that the argument for the makeText() method was incorrect! Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 4):

```
Toast.makeText(encrypt.this,String.valueOf(chars[i]), 0).show();
```

instead of

```
Toast.makeText(encrypt.this,chars[i], 0).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
Toast.makeText(encrypt.this,chars[i] + "", 0).show();
```

it has the same way with Ram's

Answer (score 0):

the `chars[i]` is integer value. If you look closely in your error log you will see

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x61
```

(if you pass integer parameter, android will lookup for a resource with this Id)

you can print the character from the string directly:

```
Toast.makeText(encrypt.this,PT[i], 0).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the edit text (layout resource)is not available when reading the data from it. Just check whether you are able to get no null value when you do

```
EditText edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditView);
```

log edt1(either through log, system.out.println);